Sound radiated by wind instrument
My understanding of how a wind instrument (modeled as a tube open on both ends) works is as follows:

Person blows into one of the open ends to create pressure waves.
These pressure waves are reflected off the other end since at an open end there must be a pressure node.
The geometry of the instrument is such that we have resonance in the form of standing waves.

This might be obvious, but is it true then that the sound we hear from an instrument is from the small percentage of energy that is transmitted and radiated instead of reflected at the open end of the instrument? And what percent of the energy is transmitted? I'd imagine then the inside of the instrument would be much, much louder than the outside.
